# Typing removal of a key from an object

Tags: typescript

I'd like to setup a function to remove a key from an object using the code:

```
type GenericObject = {
  [key: string]: any;
};

const removeKey = (
  inputObject: GenericObject,
  key: string,
) => {
  if (!inputObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return inputObject;
  }

  const {
    [key]: _,
    ...rest
  } = inputObject;

  return rest;
};
```

This works to an extent, in that it removes a key from an object, but I feel like the typing could be better. Really, **I'd like typescript to be able to know that this will return an object as the same type which was passed, only without the specified key.**

I looked into [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) which seems to be useful for this kind of thing, but unfortunately I haven't been able to configure it to work. I feel like this is possible, but I've yet to come across a way to do this effectively. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the function generic, with one type parameter to capture the type of the object and one type parameter to capture the string literal type representing the key passed in.

```
const removeKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  inputObject: T,
  key: K,
) => {
  if (!inputObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return inputObject;
  }

  const {
    [key]: _,
    ...rest
  } = inputObject;

  return rest;
};

let a = removeKey({ a: 10, b: 10 }, 'b');
a.a // ok
a.b // err
```

Given your use of spread, in typescript 3.2 the compiler will automatically type the return of the function as `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>` which is what you need to use if you want to remove a key `K` from the type `T`.

**Edit**

A version that works for 2.2, ( but with a lot more type assertions) is:

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];  
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Diff<keyof T, K>>;  

const removeKey = <T, K extends keyof T>(
    inputObject: T,
    key: K,
): Omit<T, K> => {
    if (!inputObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return inputObject as any as Omit<T, K>;
    }

    const result = Object.assign({}, inputObject);
    delete result[key]
    return result as any as Omit<T, K>;;
};
```

Comment: Many thanks! I'm trying to get this to work with my code, it seems completely fine but I think I'm having an issue with my typescript version. I was on 2.2, which seems to have a problem spreading generics.

Comment: @OliverRadini uh .. 2.2 is OLD, we might be able to do something .. but I am not sure ..

Comment: Ha yes I was starting from a boilerplate and didn't check the version. I'll work on upgrading the typescript version and resolve it that way, I don't have any particular tie to 2.2

Comment: Unfortunately anything 3.2+ breaks my project for some reason, so I cannot yet upgrade typescript to a version where this is supported

Comment: @OliverRadini I think I we can build an omit type for 2.2, let me check

Comment: That would be much appreciated, though I'm also struggling to find a way past the error `TS2700: Rest types may only be created from object types.`

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, which is both interesting and useful! I'm certainly learning more about how typings work in typescript. I've put this into the typescript playground, and it complains that `keyof T does not satisfy constraint 'string`; is there a way to further specify the type of T there? (Sorry, I cannot link to the playground here)

Comment: @OliverRadini in newer versions of TS, keyof is more than strings, the diff would have to be: `type Diff<T extends PropertyKey, U extends PropertyKey> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];`

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you for your continued patience and help with this. I've learnt a great deal about how the typing system works!