# Return an object without certain keys (dynamic, typesafe)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a "except"-method in TypeScript.
The purpose would be something like this:

```js
const obj = { a: true, b: 1, c: 'test', d: false }
const objExcept = except(obj, 'b', 'd')
```

My problem is not the actual key exclusion, but the **typesafe** return value.
Ideally accessing `objExcept.b` should give me an error, cause the return value is:

```
objExcept: { a: boolean, c: string } = { a: true, c: 'test' }`
```

This is my current implementation

```js
export function except<
  T extends Dictionary,
  K extends any[],
  R extends Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>>
> (value: T, ...exceptions: K): R {
  const copy: Record<string: any> = {}
  for (const key in value) {
    if (!value.hasOwnProperty(key) || exceptions.includes(key)) continue

    copy[key] = value[key]
  }

  return copy as R
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I asked something slightly similar a while ago, does it help at all?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54199582/typing-removal-of-a-key-from-an-object

Comment: @OliverRadini forgot I answered that :))

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir haha I was wondering if you'd answer this one, your answer to my question was very useful!

Comment: Thanks for the hint @OliverRadini. The problem is quite similar but for my purpose i had to be able to exclude 1+ keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close you just need to get the compiler to infer literal types for `K`. The best way to do this is to restrict the items in `K` to `keyof T`. This will also check that property keys are part of the target object.

```
export function except<
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends Array<keyof T>,
  R extends Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K[number]>>
> (value: T, ...exceptions: K): R {
  const copy: Record<string, any> = {}
  for (const key in value) {
    if (!value.hasOwnProperty(key) || exceptions.includes(key)) continue

    copy[key] = value[key]
  }

  return copy as R
}

const obj = { a: true, b: 1, c: 'test', d: false }
const objExcept = except(obj, 'b', 'd')
objExcept.a
objExcept.b //err
```

If you want to allow any keys not necessarily just known keys of `T` you can also use `K extends Array<PropertyKey>` this will allow any key but exclude any keys that overlap from `T`

Comment: Thank you so much (actually: again ;)). I work's perfectly fine now